# Get facebook logged in user information

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using following bunch of code in button action to invite facebook friend.

```
    [FBWebDialogs
      presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
      message:NSLocalizedString(@"FBinviteMessage", nil)
      title:nil
      parameters:nil
      handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
     ];
```

This code shows a login view on its own if the user is not logged in. What I want to know is that how to get logged in user information if using above code.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in Social framework in iOS? Its much easier.

Comment: What type is ```FBWebDialogResult result```? I guess it might be something like ```NSData``` or ```NSDictionary```? If so, you can parse the data from those and store them in arrays/strings and then use that for your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use FBWebDialogs, it is deprecated by Facebook.   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.9/class/FBWebDialogs

Please refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) to get latest SDK and use Facebook documentation for implementing this.

> **Facebook Developer Website has the best documentation for implementing FacebookSDK**